# Javascript form in Blogger (Blogspot)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, adobe, blogger

I have an issue. I need a contact form for my blog in Blogger (lacasadeestudio.blogspot.com). Actually, Its works with Adobe form but I dont like this way. Is possible to create a form with Javascript in Blogger and send the data by mail when the users click submit?. Please take a look of Adobe Form:

```
http://lacasadeestudio.blogspot.com/p/contacto.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a google spreadsheet as a form and embed that inside your Blogger page. I have used that in the contact us page of EesanEnergy.com

You can have a trigger set to send an email in your spreadsheet when somebody submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using a service called [jotform](http://www.jotform.com/) on my [blog](http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/p/contact.html) . maybe you could try it.